# What is the best inter-process communication approach or software for programs written in different languages?

Tags: javascript, java, c++, programming, go

I want my C++ and JavaScript programs to communicate with Java and Go programs. And I want it to do with the lowest possible latency.

I am familiar with standard input/output (aka `iostream`/`stdio`). Is it the fastest? I also have heard of AMQ protocol (Kafka, RabbitMQ) but I suspect they are more suitable for communication over network and focus on throughput rather than latency.

Comment: If all within one operating system (which?), why not use o/s messages? Or are you looking for a function call mechanism?